# ¿Cómo ejecutar un servicio de Windows en un proyecto ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, servicio

Tengo una aplicación web en (`ASP.NET`) que necesito estar cada cierto tiempo verificando algunos registros de una base de datos en `SQL Server 2014`. Esto es para cambiar el estado de un registro cada que se cumpla una condición relacionada con la lógica de negocio. Mi duda es si implemento un servicio de Windows que sea el que haga los cambios de estado de los registros en la base de datos, pero al ser un proyecto web instalado en la `Intranet` de la empresa donde será implantado, este se ejecuta siempre aunque no se use el sitio, o ¿cuál seria el paso para que esto suceda?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si necesitas un servicio de windows, créalo. Pero eso no tiene nada que ver con que tu proyecto sea asp.net, deberás pensar que debe hacer ese servicio (notificar a alguien?) y como estableces comunicación con tu aplicación. No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Alvaro, te recomiendo que mires esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447220/9406627
Saludos.

Comment: Al disponer de un SQL Server 2014, te recomiendo que hagas un paquete SSIS y lo ejecutes en el SQL, de esta forma el propio SSIS puede ejecutarse mediante un Trigger cuando se cumpla una condición, o bien ejecutándolo en función de un calendario. Así mismo, el propio SSIS podrá cambiar el registro en función del evento creado. 
También puedes desde el SSIS, ejecutar cualquier aplicación ASP.net, fichero exe, etc...

Comment: Pikoh, la comunicacion con la base de datos es via Entity Framework, el servicio tendria que vefificar algunos registros que tengan un estado de espera, ese registro tiene una hora de confeccion del registro, si pasada una hora el registro no ha sido cambiado de estado, entonces es ahí donde el servicio lo haria automaticamente ya que la logica de negocio asi lo solicita.

Comment: JoseDEV, gracias por tu comentario, investigaré SSIS pues lo desconocía, pero por lo que lei en tu comentario es eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias opciones para implementar lo que planteas, pero usar un sitio web no es una de ellas, definir una task en una pagina o servicio no es lo correcto

Si podrias evaluar

- Servicio de Windows usando un Timer
- Servicio de Windows usando alguna libreria como ser:   [Quartz.NET - Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/index.html)
  la cual permite definir un scheduler de la tarea
- Definir una task en windows, quizas ayudandote con alguna libreria como ser
  [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)

No se si conocias pero Windows 10 tiene la capacidad de definir `Task Scheduler`

[How to Automatically Run Programs and Set Reminders With the Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/)

Como veras opciones hay muchas pero no deberian ser dentro de un ambiente web

Comment: Gracias por tus recomendaciones, el asunto es que el proyecto es Web y esta casi terminado exceptuando ese detalle, Ya estaba empezando la primer opción que me diste. Siendo esa entonces, es necesario crear un ejecutable del servicio y implantarlo en el servidor donde se va a alojar el sitio para que el mismo verifique su condicion y ejecute los cambios a la base de datos cuado sea necesario? Saludos

Comment: Por lo general se desarrolla un proceso local en el servicio cuando se conoce que este sera pesado y demora, alojar un proceso que tarde varios minutos en la web no es aconsejable. Ahora bien si el servicio es simple y demora poco podrias dejarlo en un web service he invocar este cada cierto tiempo desde un window service con el timer, para eso usaras las clase WebClient o HttpClient, invocando la url del servicio que ejecuta la accion